# how do I insert a api json to my database

Tags: php, json, mysqli

good day im trying somethings with php and a api json to make te info from the api to a json array an then to mij database but it doesn't do anything can some one help me

this is my script

```
<?Php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","beers");
$url = file_get_contents("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers");
$json = json_decode($url, true);


foreach ($json as $row) {


        $sql =  "INSERT INTO Brewdog (naam, tagline, omschrijving) VALUES ('".$row['name']."','".$row['tagline']."',,'".$row['description']."')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);




}
echo "klaar is kees";
?>
```

Comment: in line 10 `('".$row['name']."','".$row['tagline']."',,'".$row['description']."')";` you placed 2 `,` between tagline and description .

Comment: i have get rid of , but it doesn't work

Comment: maybe there is single-quote `'` in your json values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple answer maybe there is `'` single-quote in your json values.

**Old solution:**

> **Security Warning:** Escaping is inadequate to prevent SQL injection, use prepared
>   statements instead. Use the strategy outlined below at your own risk.
>   (Also, mysql_real_escape_string() was removed in PHP 7.)

You can using `mysqli::real_escape_string` to fix it.

```
    <?Php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","beers");
$url = file_get_contents("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers");
$json = json_decode($url, true);

foreach ($json as $row) {

        $sql =  "INSERT INTO Brewdog (naam, tagline, omschrijving) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row['name'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row['tagline'])."',,'".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row['description'])."')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

}
echo "klaar is kees";
?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

**UPDATE security issue**
use mysqli prepare in order avoiding sql injection

```
$stmt = $connectn->prepare('INSERT INTO Brewdog (naam, tagline, omschrijving) VALUES (?, ?, ?');
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $row['name'],$row['tagline'],$row['tagline']); // 's' specifies the variable type => 'string'

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: i have tried this but it doesn't work bij my

Comment: comment the `mysqli_query($connect, $sql);` and just add the result of `$sql` into an array and then print it and check each sql. `$logarray=[];
foreach ($json as $row) {
$sql =  "INSERT INTO ...";
//mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$logarray[]=$sql
}
var_dump($logarray);`

Comment: it gives back array(25) { [0]=> string(75) "INSERT INTO `Brewdog` (`naam`, `tagline`, `omschrijving`) VALUES ('','','')" [1]=> string(75) "

Comment: make sure `$json` and `$row` have values

Answer (score -1):

it dosen't do anything because there is something wrong with your SQL Query .

i suggest you write your SQL Query like this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Brewdog (naam, tagline, omschrijving) VALUES ('$row[name]','$row[tagline]','$row[description]')";
```

i think it's more easy to read .

and you may want to see SQL error so use this

```
if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
    echo "Record Created";
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($connect);
}
```

**Update**

i checked the api and there is some `'` in your `tagline` you should use [mysqli_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php)

Comment: i have tried this but it doesn't work bij my

Comment: @fathi so when you added `mysqli_error` what was your error ?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.